# Minimizing the function $\sqrt{2x} - \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+8x}}{2} \right\rceil$ for $x > 0$

Tags: optimization

How can you find the minimum of $\sqrt{2x} - \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+8x}}{2} \right\rceil$  for positive integer values of $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as $x \to \infty$, the function approaches 0 from below. You have points of non-differentiability at values with 
$$\sqrt{1+8x}/2 \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow x = (4n^2 - 1)/8 \; \exists n,$$
but at other points the function increases; you check this by differentiation. Also the sequence $\sqrt{(4n^2-1)/4} - n$ is increasing for $n \ge 1$, so the values at these non-differentiable points are increasing. To find the minimum, you should therefore need only check the first few positive integer values.

Comment: That is perfectly making sense. Interestingsly enough, WolframAlpha does not find a global minimum for "Minimize[{(2*x)^0.5 - Ceiling[((1+8*x)^0.5/2)], x>0},x]".